# flutter build apk --release failing with error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, build, release

**Update**

Okay I noticed that this issue is not just Android specific,  `flutter build ios --release` also fails with similar type error log - https://pastebin.pl/view/4539cc24

`flutter build apk --release` failing with error :

> Script '/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1102
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
>   Process 'command '/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

But flutter pub get, flutter run is working.
I've tried doing flutter clean, checked all pubspec.yaml dependencies, updated android build.gradle minimum version to satisfy dependency requirements.

Project environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
Flutter version: 2.10.2(stable channel)

Has anyone faced anything such? If so what could be some possible solutions to this issue?

Comment: flutter run --release works ?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63087819/11675817) has suggested 3 steps to solve the problem:

```
Step 1. flutter build apk --debug

Step 2. flutter build apk --profile

Step 3. flutter build apk --release
```

If it doesn't help you, you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69402329/11675817) too.

Comment: Step 2. fails with same error, just instead of release showing profile -  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildProfile'.

Comment: And you've tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/69402329/11675817 too?

Comment: Yes, didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

you need clean your build in file android with `cd android` & `gradlew clean`

Then, `cd ..` & `flutter build apk --release`

or

```
flutter build apk --release -vv
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was with Riverpod usage. As after upgrading to riverpod 1 context.read doesn't work. earlier we could obtain context using global navigation keys. We were trying to obtain `Ref` from Dart class, which caused the errors. Using ProviderContainer instead solved the issue.