# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'D:\Kerja\******\*******\android\build.gradle' line: 9 -- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-update

I am updating to the latest flutter update since my terminal telling me there is a new flutter update. this is when my error show up when I try to run the app into my emulator

```
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Kerja\*****\*****\android\build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

for further information, here's my current build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i tried to run this solution before asking this question
[How to solve the error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314404/how-to-solve-the-error-failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-where-script).

the problem starts when i try to update the kotlin version manually from my build.gradle

Comment: You have to change in  gradlewrapper.properties  distribution url to or based on your classpath you specified in project level gradle file https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip

Comment: the solution you give will use the previous version of my gradle file. I had fix my problem by creating a new project with flutter  3.19. the main problem actually, i just cant follow the proper way how flutter change their build gradle in android from 3.16 to 3.19. I suggest anyone who reach this post, maybe you can try create a new project and try to move all file in lib folder to the new project. with some error adjusment, you are ready to go